# How to SUM DISTINCT in a calculated field for pivot table

Tags: sql-server, excel, pivot-table

I have data like this coming from an SQL query:

```
REF   ORDER   R_UNITS   R_STOCK   COMPONENT   C_NEEDED   C_STOCK   HELPER
TOY1   SP1      500       350      BLISTER       500       500        1
TOY1   SP2      400       350      BLISTER       400       500        1
TOY1   SP3      100       350      BLISTER       100       500        1
TOY2   SP1      200       200      BLISTER       200       500        1
TOY2   SP4      300       200      BLISTER       300       500        1 
TOY3   SP1      600       300      BLISTER       600       500        1  
TOY3   SP1      400       300        BOX         400       300        1
```

And I would like to pivot it like this:

```
FILTER ORDER: ALL

COMPONENT   R_UNITS   Σ R_STOCK   Σ R_TO_PACKAGE   C_STOCK    Σ C_TO_BUY
BLISTER      2100        850          1250           500         750
BOX          400         300          100            300          0
```

**R_STOCK** should be a calculated field iterating unique values over the data and summarising the results: 350 TOY1 + 200 TOY2 + 300 TOY3 = 850

I think PowerPivot SUMX would do the job, but my Excel is not compatible with PowerPivot

I cannot group my SQL query by REF and COMPONENT because I'd like to add a filter with ORDER to my pivot table, so it shows different results based on the order selected (SP1, SP2...).

I tried pretty much everything that came to my mind. I tried to divide R_STOCK by count(REF) with SQL. But then it returns a non variable value (for example 850/3 for TOY1, which is correct if I don't filter), but I want it to vary depending on the number of rows (affected by the ORDER filter added to the pivot table).

I don't know if I'm explaining myself. Ask me if I need to clarify anything

PD: I can add new columns with SQL or PowerQuery if needed.

Comment: *"I tried pretty much everything that came to my mind."* So what were those attempts? YOu haven't included any in your question? Why didn't those attempts work?

Comment: I fail to see how filtering by `ORDER` influences grouping by `REF` and `COMPONENT`. Filtering in a `WHERE` clause is applied before `GROUP BY`. You mean sth else by the term filtering?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos As far as I know, if I group by REF and COMPONENT, I'm forced to group by ORDER aswell. ORDER will usually return more than one row for each REF, so  I can't sum nor average R_STOCK (it repeats the same value for each REF).

Comment: @Larnu I tried to divide R_STOCK by count(REF) with SQL. I also tried to group rows by REF and by COMPONENT, but since I want to keep the ORDER field as a pivot table filter, it keeps returning more than one row for each REF, repeating R_STOCK value. I also thought about using a DAX formula (I think CALCULATE can SUM DISTINCT, not sure), but my excel is not compatible with powerpivot

Comment: @giorgosBetsos Sorry. I missunderstood. The filter is not for SQL but for the Pivot Table.

Comment: What version of Excel? This seems like something easily doable in Power Query. But maybe you have a Mac version?  (And I don't see a need for a filter if you are using Power Query).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm using MO Standard 2016. How could I do it with Power Query? I need that filter to the Pivot Table to make it more dynamic

Comment: The documentation indicates Power Pivot **IS** available in 2016. Why is it not in yours? And using Power Query, it is trivial to `Group By` **Component** and output the columns you show.  What is not so trivial is how to have a two line output, but still be able to "dynamically" filter on different order numbers. You'd need to have some kind of dropdown that triggers a query refresh, or also do a `Group by` **Order #**, which would result in two lines per order #,  (or edit the query each time, changing the filter within the query).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Power Pivot is not available for 2016 Standard, only for 2016 Professional, Stand Alone, etc. Sadly, editing the query is not an option because the final user doesn't know how to. I thought about using a dropdown macro that triggers a query refresh, as you say, but I don't know how to refresh that dropdown based on the orders available, and I don't know how to link the macro to the query either (I would need to somehow link that dropdown to PowerQuery, right? I'm new with M-coding)

Comment: There are a number of methods. Seems like a simple one would be to filter the original table. You add a column to the original table that will contain a zero if it is hidden, and non-zero if it is visible. Use the `SUBTOTAL` function for that. The filter on that column at the beginning of your query.

Comment: To make it work in a Pivot Table I would need to link a dropdown to my query, right? @RonRosenfeld

How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: The dropdowns would be at the top of the column in your Source data table.  So when you refresh your `Power Query`, it will output a filtered result.  If you want the drop down elsewhere, you'll have to filter your original data using a VBA macro; and then update the query.

Comment: Also, if you have control over the SQL query, you could apply the filter at that level.